# Failed to play video while the iPhone is locked

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, background-process, video-player

I am building an **alarm** that uses **Youtube videos** for the alarm sound. So the app will work in the background `while the phone is locked`.

What I've done for now is I get the youtube video and pass it to the player. Actually once the player is working and even the phone is locked or in the background, it will keep playing the video.

But the *current issue* is that `when I am scheduling playing the video to be played when the phone is locked it doesn't play the video at all`. Here is the block of code I am playing the video in:

```swift
XCDYouTubeClient.default().getVideoWithIdentifier(videoId) { [self] video, error in
   if let video {
      AVPlayerViewControllerManager.shared.video = video
      guard let url = video.streamURL else { return }
      self.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
         
      // Schedule playing the video after 3 sec (Just for testing)
      let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { timer in
          self.player?.play()
      }

      RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
                
      self.player?.audiovisualBackgroundPlaybackPolicy = .continuesIfPossible
  } else {
      print(error!.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

**Hints:**

- I am using `SwiftUI`
- `XCDYouTubeClient` is a 3rd party library to get the Youtube video.

Here is what I recieve in the debugger when trying to play the video while the phone is locked:

```swift
MEDeviceStreamClient.cpp:431   
AQME Default-InputOutput: client stopping after failed start: <AudioQueueObject@0x13b0c0c00; 
Unknown figplayer; [74708]; play>; running count now 0
```

Thank you

I expect to play the video even if the phone is locked or the app is in the background

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I expect to play the video even if the phone is locked or the app is in the background

Your expectations are unrealistic. Your app won't get any processor time when it is in the background or the device is locked. That's enforced by Apple, to reduce battery drain. Only certain types of apps are allowed to run from the background (streaming music players, turn-by-turn direction apps, VoIP apps, and maybe 1 or 2 others.)

Comment: Thank you @Duncan C for your answer. 

I have seen an app do so, but I don't how it is happening. So do you have an idea about how this happened?